# Center three col-md-3 columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to have three col-md-3 columns and center them. Offset doesn't work, because I'd have to offset the first column for a column and a half. So is there another way to do this?

Here's the outline of the code:

```css
.col-md-3 {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">First column</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Second column</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Third column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The answers I managed to find on SO were all related to Bootstrap 3 and lower. And didn't work with Bootstrap 4. Can someone take a look and let me know?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Flexbox utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) are your friend.
You can use `justify-content-center` on `.row` in this case.

```css
.row {
    background-color: lavender;
}

.col-md-3 {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">First column</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Second column</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Third column</div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, dferenc! This was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

Apply `justify-content:center` to the row.

As indicated BS4 has their own class for this `.justify-content-center`

```css
.col-md-3 {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.row {
  justify-content:center;
}
/* or apply the class "justify-content-center" to the row */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">First column</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Second column</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Third column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't alter global framework classes, like `.row`. Instead, write an additional class, for example `row-centered`.

Comment: This is just a demo...I'm sure BS4 has there own class for this.

Answer (score 1):

how about `flex`:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-3">First column</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Second column</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Third column</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```